# How do I hide a scrollbar after scrolling and make it visible again on scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, scrollbar

My intention is to hide my scrollbar (i.e, hidden by SLIDING TO THE RIGHT), after scrolling (let's say, like 2 or 3 seconds after I'm done scrolling)

And to make it visible again, soon as I start scrolling (i.e, visible by SLIDING IN FROM THE RIGHT)

VIEW CODE SNIPPET:

```css
div::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
  /* helps remove scrollbar which resizes or shifts list items */
  /* display: none; */
}

div::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: #444444;
}

div::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment {
  background-color: rgba(108, 92, 231, 0.65);
}

div::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement {
  background-color: rgba(108, 92, 231, 0.65);
}

div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: rgba(108, 92, 231, 0.7);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: rgba(108, 92, 231, 1);
}

div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #ececec;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p style="height: 300vh;">Just some tall paragraph to force DIV scrollbars....</p>
</div>
```

Please help me everyone (I'D BE SO GRATEFUL!)

:D

Comment: This cannot be achieved using CSS-alone, and as you well know (since the JavaScript tag is there) - do you have any JS code to share? Some `"scroll"` Event? Please show what you tried. From the code given above there's no sign of any issue. Read: [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since CSS does not have timeouts and clearing of timeouts - Use JavaScript

- Use `Element.classList` to add and remove a class
- Use `setTimeout()` set at 2500ms, but every time a scroll event is triggered remove the previous pending timeout using `clearTimeout`. Logically, after you finished scrolling the last timeout that was set will, after 2.5s trigger finally the class removal.
- Use a CSS class like `.is-scrolling` to there define the desired scrollbar styles (which otherwise are transparent by default)

```js
const showScrollbars = (evt) => {

  const el = evt.currentTarget;
  clearTimeout(el._scrolling); // Cancel pending class removal
  
  el.classList.add("is-scrolling"); // Add class 
  
  el._scrolling = setTimeout(() => { // remove the scrolling class after 2500ms
    el.classList.remove("is-scrolling");
  }, 2500);
};

document.querySelectorAll("[data-scrollbars]").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("scroll", showScrollbars); 
});
```

```css
[data-scrollbars] {
  width: 500px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: #ececec;
  overflow: auto;
}

[data-scrollbars]::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
}

[data-scrollbars]::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: transparent;
}

[data-scrollbars]::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

[data-scrollbars].is-scrolling::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: #777;
}

[data-scrollbars].is-scrolling::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div data-scrollbars>
  <p style="height: 300vh;">
    Just some tall paragraph to force DIV scrollbars...<br>
    Scroll me! (<<< PS: See the problem?!)
  </p>
</div>
```

I would highly not advise you hide scrollbars. Scrollbars are a visual hint to the user that there's actually content to be scrolled. Do a simple A/B testing. For half of your visitors show the scrollbar. For the other half, do that funky stuff - and don't be surprised that your click trough-rate for the below-the-fold portion of the app (or element) has fewer-to-none interactions by that second group of users.

Answer (score -2):

I am thinking about what if user do not have any mouse wheel for scrolling and if user scroll with the actually using scroll bar.
Anyway please search for slim fading scroll bar example at google. You will find some examples for the slim scroll maybe it’s not invisible but it’s transparent and have a good shape.

Comment: As far as this is a great Accessibility-wise concerns commentary; an answer saying: *"Please do some research on Google"* cannot be accounted as a Good Quality answer - not in the expected format for this site.  For more info read [How to provide a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I don't know how to say THANK YOU!!! for not only helping me out - with my question - but also for helping me caution this person - not sure if he just wanted to make me look stupid :(    I'm still learning. THANK YOU SIR!    I think I also see what you were trying to explain to me (i.e., regarding the user's end of the application's usage). Now I think I can decide whether to implement it in my application or not. Once again, THANK YOU SIR, for helping me out (- with advice on whether to implement it or not) and for defending me by speaking to that user. MERCI BEAUCOUP.

Comment: @MattDon Not a problem :) But what I don't understand is why you accepted this answer than? :)

Comment: @CaferAydın hehe this got really messy and funny :) I didn't wrote that :) Matt (the Original Poster) did

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan sorry about that. You are right. Surfing at stackoverflow with phone is painful.